# Can R objects (NumericVector, NumericMatrix) be used in std::pair?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am new to Rcpp (and so cpp as well), and I'm getting stuck on how to use std::pair properly.

I am working with graphs, and the data structure for the graph is:
`std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, double> > >`

I need to extend the concept of a single weight. I have written a couple of minimalistic examples. All of which takes in a matrix, and returns the same matrix (after running through the required operations it will go through in the actual code. So it is essential that the graph data structure is `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, ?> > >`, that the `holding` vector performs push backs, and that a `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` is returned using the elements of `holding` at the end):

1.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
  NumericMatrix test_stdvector(Rcpp::NumericMatrix x) {
  
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<double> > > holding(x.nrow());
    
    for (int i=0; i < x.nrow(); i++) {
      NumericVector nv_x = x.row(i);
      std::vector<double> b =  Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> >(nv_x);
      holding.push_back(std::make_pair(i, b));
    }
  
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix y(x.nrow(), x.ncol());
    for (int i=0; i < x.nrow(); i++) {
    
      NumericVector b = wrap(holding[i].second);
      y(i, _) = b;
    }
    
    return y;
  }
')
```

2. 

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
  NumericMatrix test_numericvector(Rcpp::NumericMatrix x) {
  
    std::vector<std::pair<int, Rcpp::NumericVector> > holding(x.nrow());
    
    for (int i=0; i < x.nrow(); i++) {
      holding.push_back(std::make_pair(i, x(i, _)));
    }
  
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix y(x.nrow(), x.ncol());
    for (int i=0; i < x.nrow(); i++) {
    
      y(i, _) = holding[i].second;
    }
    
    return y;
  }
')
```

Both functions compile fine, however for input `x = matrix(1:100, nrow=10)`, the output is weird:

```
               [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]          [,6]          [,7]          [,8]          [,9]
 [1,] 1.356944e-311 2.121996e-314 1.356944e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355967e-311 1.356944e-311 1.356944e-311 2.121996e-314
 [2,] 1.356944e-311 9.881313e-324 1.356944e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.356944e-311 2.121996e-314
 [3,] 1.356944e-311 9.881313e-324 1.356944e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.356944e-311 2.121996e-314
 [4,] 1.356944e-311 9.881313e-324 1.356944e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.356944e-311 2.121996e-314
 [5,] 1.356944e-311 9.881313e-324 1.356944e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.356944e-311 2.121996e-314
 [6,] 1.356944e-311 9.881313e-324 1.356944e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.356944e-311 2.121996e-314
 [7,] 1.356944e-311 9.881313e-324 1.356944e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.356944e-311 2.262910e-314
 [8,] 1.356944e-311 9.881313e-324 1.356944e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.356944e-311 2.121996e-314
 [9,] 1.356944e-311 9.881313e-324 1.356944e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.356944e-311 2.121996e-314
[10,] 1.356944e-311 9.881313e-324 1.356944e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.355961e-311 1.356944e-311 2.121996e-314
              [,10]
 [1,] 1.356944e-311
 [2,] 1.356944e-311
 [3,] 1.356944e-311
 [4,] 1.356944e-311
 [5,] 1.356944e-311
 [6,] 1.356944e-311
 [7,] 1.356944e-311
 [8,] 1.356944e-311
 [9,] 1.356944e-311
[10,] 1.356944e-311
```

Can someone please explain what is going on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend careful debugging and index checking, possibly with smaller examples.

You can also print the matrix on the way to check you get the data at the start, a simple `print(x);` at the C++ level will do. Same for `y` before returning.

I would start with maybe 3x3 examples and would try to get those right.   And I don't think we have converters for `std::pair`.

Lastly, sometimes it is the little things: in  `y(i, _) = holding[i].second;` you are actually doing several things at once as you both extract and reassign.  Sometimes it helps to extract to a temporary variable, and then assign that temporary variable.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, it looks like when calling `push_back` the holding vector added the vector outside it's range since it was initialised with `holding(x.nrow())`.